# if $\operatorname{Res}_{z_0}f = 0$, then $f$ has a primitive in some deleted neighborhood of $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $z_0$ be an isolated singularity of $f$. Prove that if $\operatorname{Res}_{z_0}f = 0$, then $f$ has a primitive in some deleted neighborhood of $z_0$

I know that if we assume $f$ has a primitive, then we can use Morera's theorem to prove that $\operatorname{Res}_{z_0}f = 0$. But, I don't know how to do the opposite side. Can someone please show me how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the Taylor (or Laurent if it has negative terms) series of $f$. The only term without an anti-derivative is the $x^{-1}$ term. But here, that's zero. So we can anti-differentiate the Taylor series term-wise. Call this function $g$. Use facts about uniform compact convergence of $f$ to justify the convergence of $g$. Similarly, you'll see that $g'=f$.